# Next Image has invalid "width" or "height" property. These should be numeric values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I tried to use my style definition for Next image element. But got this error.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Image with src "/images/search_icon_green.svg" has invalid "width" or "height" property. These should be numeric values.
```

However, I have this as my image component.

```
 <Image
   src="/images/search_icon_green.svg"
   alt="search"
   width={`${spacing(64)}`}
   height={`${spacing(64)}`}
   style={{ marginTop: '-14px' }}
  />
```

My Global Style Defintion.

```
spacing: {
 64: '64px',
 68: '68px',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `width` and `height` need to be numeric values. Your `spacing` object is returning strings.

It should look something like this:

```js
<Image
   src="/images/search_icon_green.svg"
   alt="search"
   width={64}
   height={64}
   style={{ marginTop: '-14px' }}
  />
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I'm trying to use my already made styling definition.

Comment: But since `next/image` only accepts numeric value on that prop you have to pass numeric values. workaround is writing a helper function like `function convert(value: string) { return Number(value.replaceAll('px', '')) };` and pass that return value to as prop

Comment: `export function spacing(key: SpacingKeys) {
  return `var(--spacing-${key})`;
}
`

Comment: I made my function this way

Answer (score 0):

spacing is not a function, you can either change spacing to helper or use it's key

spacing as a helper :

```
const spacing = (size)=>{
  return `${size}px`
}
```

or use index :

```
width={`${spacing['64']}`}
height={`${spacing['64']}`}
```

Comment: index didn't work.

Comment: export function spacing(key: SpacingKeys) {   return var(--spacing-${key}); } 

My helper function

Comment: how did you define your css variables ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Change your width & height to:

`` width={parseInt(`${spacing(64)}`)} `` and `` height={parseInt(`${spacing(64)}`)} ``